# How to call a java or run java program from sql script

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Is it possible to run java code from sql or sql procedure? I have the following code. I need to run it from a procedure. Could we do this or I have to find another way to do things?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class A{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            String format = "jpg";
            String fileName = "FullScreenshot." + format;

            Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));

            System.out.println("A full screenshot saved!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the database you are using..? if it is Oracle, you have the solution here   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm

Comment: Ok, i'll look into that.